# Question about the converge of a random sequence involving a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Consider a random variable $X$ that is Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I am trying to understand whether the following statement holds:

\begin{equation}
\frac{X}{n}  \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{\text{a.s.}} 0.
\end{equation}
I feel that this statement should not hold for almost sure convergence but it should hold for in probability convergence. I used Markov inequality and could not prove the result for almost sure convergence, because an assumption of the form $\mathbb{E} [ |X|] < \infty$ was needed. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: $\mathbb{E} [ |X|] < \infty$ is true for a Gaussian distributed random variable.  I think it is bounded above by $|\mu|+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$ or more simply by  $|\mu|+\sigma$

Comment: I think you are right! Thanks for the input!

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question. For each $\omega \in \Omega$, $X(\omega)$ is a real number which does not depend on $n$. Therefore $X(\omega)/n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Do you mean that $X_n$ is a sequence of Gaussian random variables and you want to investigate $X_n/n$?

Comment: No it is $\frac{X}{n}$. That's what I also thought but since Gaussian random variables are unbounded I wasn't sure if this is a rigorous argument.

Comment: Yep that argument is rigorous, you do not need it to be bounded. The point is that the result holds $\omega$ by $\omega$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian: Looks like an answer to me :-)